# Get User Tag Using His ID IN Sharding ? Discord.js

Tags: discord.js, sharding

**Hi ! I Need To Get A User Tag Using His Id In Sharding
I tried This Code But Doesn't Work :**

```
let tag = await client.shard.broadcastEval(`this.users.get("id").tag`)
```

**Any One Can Help Me Please!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const user = (await client.shard.broadcastEval('this.users.cache.get("id")')).find(u => u)
if (user) {
  let tag = user.tag
  // do something with the tag
} else {
  // the user wasn't found
}
```